# Increase .net controller MaxResponseBufferSize on controller level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel

I have read the MaxResponseBufferSize can be set at startup via code like

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(x => x.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = 10485760).UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Is there a porvisioning of setting that limit on controller/action level instead at startup.
Like adding it in some attribute there

Comment: `[RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]` ? Not sure it will help though, never used it

Comment: I know about this one. Purpose of this one is incoming request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

`MaxResponseBufferSize` limit is a low-level Kestrel implementation detail that is independent of `HttpContext`. It has no idea which controller or action is executing at the moment (or finished executing), so you cannot tweak the way it works within an action.

The reason `RequestSizeLimit` is configurable unlike `MaxResponseBufferSize` is that the request body is not read by default unless you implicitly (using model binding `[FromBody]`) or explicitly (`Request.Body.Read*` methods) read the body stream from the request. This happens at the endpoint level, so ASP.NET Core exposes relevant piping to make this easier to configure, if needed.